# Is it really necessary for datetime instruction to be this long?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

I inherited python code that includes:

```
import time
import datetime

stamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
stamp = stamp[0:19]       #trim to seconds
print "\n%s\n" %stamp
```

The third instruction line seems to be unusually long and verbose for returning the current date and time:

### 2018-04-18 23:18:02

Although it works, is there a shorter instruction to perform the task?

Comment: You could make it shorter by only importing the objects and functions that you need from datetime and time, e.g. from time import time. Once this is done, you can use time() instead of time.time()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

There is this:

```
# while more concise now you have to deal with time zones
stamp = str(datetime.utcnow())[0:19]
```

Otherwise:

You can import exactly what you need to eliminate some of the redundancy.

```
from time import time
from datetime import datetime
```

You can define `FORMAT` to shorten it up as well. It has an added benefit of being *slightly* more explicit. If you're into that kind of thing. You may find the original version more explicit. It could go either way.

```
FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
stamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(time()).strftime(FORMAT)[0:19]
```

You may be asking if there's something that you can do that's like:

```
stamp = datetime_timestamp(FORMAT)
```

You could roll something like this:

```
def datetime_timestamp(format):
     return datetime.fromtimestamp(time()).strftime(format)[0:19]
```

Then you could call something like:

```
stamp = datetime_timestamp(FORMAT)
```

Not sure if there is a more elegant way to do it. If there isn't then *you're the boss on this one*.